# Closing browser for unhandled exception

Tags: protractor

For unhandled exception protractor immediately stops the execution but browser remains open can we close the browser for unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add browser.close() in the  `afterAll()` function of the parent `describe` function :

```
describe('description', function(){
    //some code

    afterAll(function() {
        browser.close();
    });

    //more code
});
```